# The number of distinct real roots of a polynomial

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have trying to solve this problem for a long time now. After having read related concepts, I am still stuck. The problem is as follows-
Find the number of distinct real roots of the equation

$$x^4-4x^3+12x^2+x-1=0$$

I tried to use Descartes' sign rule, but it gives a limit rather than an exact answer. I can safely say that the above equation has at least one root in the interval $[0,1]$ as $f(0)<0$ and $f(1)>0$. But I don't know how to proceed. Maybe some ideas from the differential calculus need to be applied.

Please give a clear solution or an approach such kinds of problems.
Thank You..

Comment: the equation has two real solutions and two complex one

Answer (score 8):

Let $$f(x)=x^4-4x^3+12x^2+x-1\;,$$ Then $$f'(x) = 4x^3-12x^2+24x$$

and $$f''(x)=12x^2-24x+24 = 12(x^2-2x+2)=12[(x-1)^2+1]>0\;\forall \;x\in \mathbb{R}$$

Now Using Rolles Theorem If $f(x)=0$ has $n$ real Roots, Then $f'(x)=0$ has at least $n-1$ real roots

and $f''(x)=0$ has at least $n-2$ real roots.

Or in other words If $f''(x)=0$ has $n$ roots, Then $f'(x)=0$ has at most $n+1$ roots

and $f''(x)=0$ has at most $n+1$ roots.

Now here $f''(x)=0$ has no real roots, Then $f'(x)=0$ has at most one real root and $f(x)=0$

has at most $2$ real roots.

Now Here $f(0)=-1$ and $f(1)=9$. So one root lie between $(0,1)$

and $f(-1)=15$ and $f(0) = -1$. So other root lie between $(-1,0)$

So $$f(x)=x^4-4x^3+12x^2+x-1 =0$$ has exactly two real roots.

Comment: so if $f'(x)=0$  has two real roots, $f(x)=0$ has at most three real roots? it could be 3 or 2 or 1 or 0, right?

Answer (score 4):

[Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) to the rescue!

Let's denote the polynomial in question by $p$, so that
$$p=x^4-4x^3+12x^2+x-1.$$
We first convince ourselves that the polynomial is *square free*, which it is because $\gcd(p,p')=1$. (If this were not the case, we would have needed to replace $p$ by $\frac{p}{\gcd(p,p')}$ in the subsequent steps.)

Next, we form a *Sturm sequence* associated with $p$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
p_0 &= p = x^4-4x^3+12x^2+x-1 \\
p_1 &= p' = 4x^3-12x^2+24x+1 \\
p_2 &= -\operatorname{rem}(p_0,p_1) = -3x^2-\frac{27x}{4}+\frac{3}{4} \\
p_3 &= -\operatorname{rem}(p_1,p_2) = -\frac{289x}{4}+\frac{17}{4} \\
p_4 &= -\operatorname{rem}(p_2,p_3) = -\frac{99}{289}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Let $\sigma(a)$ be the number of sign changes (the so called *variation*) in the sequence $p_0(a),\ldots,p_4(a)$. By Sturm's theorem, the number $r$ of real roots of $p$ can now be computed as
$$r=\sigma(-\infty)-\sigma(\infty)=3-1=2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Using Graph::Let $y=f(x)=x^4-4x^3+12x^2+x-1=0\Rightarrow y=x^4-4x^3+12x^2=1-x$

Draw graph of $y=x^4-4x^3+12x^2$ and $y=1-x$

Now we can draw graph of these two curve easily.

[image]

Now hare we have seen these two curve intersect each other at two distinct points..

So Number of distinct real solution of $f(x)=x^4-4x^3+12x^2+x-1=0$ is equal to $\bf{two}$

Answer (score 1):

Using Descartes Rule we get the possibilities of only $2$ real roots or none. And since $f(0)<0$ and $f(\infty)=f(-\infty)=\infty$ so $2$ real roots are confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

Since the degree of the polynomial and its coefficients are reasonably small, we might also consider ways of "decomposing" the polynomial.  (The argument here is made without calculus:  it is less efficient, but is intended to show what can be managed nonetheless.)

If we consider just the "even-function" portion, we see that $ \ x^4 + 12x^2 - 1 \ = \ 0 \ \ $ involves a biquadratic function, so its zeroes are given by
$$ x^2 \ \ = \ \ \frac{-12 \ \pm \ \sqrt{144 \ + \ 4}}{2} \ \ = \ \ -6 \ \pm \ \sqrt{37} \ \ , \ \ $$
which tells us that there are just two real zeroes, $ \ \pm  \sqrt{ \ \sqrt{37} \ - \ 6} \ \approx \ \pm 0.2877 \ \ . $ [If one does not have a calculator, one might use the binomial approximation to obtain
$$ \ \sqrt{37} \ - \ 6 \ \ = \ \ (36 + 1)^{1/2} \ - \ 6 \ \ = \ \ 6·\left(1 + \frac{1}{36} \right)^{1/2}   \ - \ 6 \ \ = \ \ 6·\left(1 + \frac12·\frac{1}{36} - 1 \right)    \ - \ 6 \ \ \approx \ \ \frac{1}{12} \ \ , $$
placing the real zeroes at $ \ \pm \frac{1}{2 \sqrt3} \ \approx \ \pm \frac{1}{3.4} \ \approx \ \pm 0.3 \ \ . $ ] It should also be observed that the range of the function is $ \ [ -1 \ , \ 12] \ $ in the interval $ \ [-1 \ , \ 1] \ \ . $

We then consider the "odd-function" portion $ \ x -  4x^3 \ \ . $  Over the interval $ \ [-1 \ , \ 0 ] \ \ , $ this is positive, so it will "raise" this part of the function curve; over $ \ [ 0 \ , \ 1 ] \ \ , $ the curve is lowered.  But we find that $ \ |x - 4x^3| < \frac13 + \frac{4}{27} = \frac{13}{27} \ $ over $ \ \left[-\frac13 \ , \ \frac13 \right] \ $  (in fact, it is considerably less) and $ \ |x - 4x^3| < 3 \ $ over $ \  [-1 \ , \ 1 ] \ \ .  $  So the "odd" terms "break" the symmetry of the "even-function", but not by enough to introduce a new $ \ x-$ intercept: the zeroes of $ \ x^4 + 12x^2 - 1 \ $ are simply "shifted to the right" by small amounts.  Hence, $ \ x^4 - 4x^3 + 12x^2 + x - 1 \ = 0 \ \ $ also has just two real roots.  [The graph below shows the even-function in green, the odd-function in red, and the complete polynomial in blue.]

[image]

Concerning the argument given by **juantheron**, his calculation for the second derivative
$$ f''(x) \ \ = \ \  12[(x-1)^2 \ + \ 1] \ > \ 0 \ \;\forall \;x\in \mathbb{R}$$
almost tells the whole story right there.  We know that for this quartic polynomial
$$ \ \lim_{x \ \rightarrow \ \pm \infty} \ x^4 - 4x^3 + 12x^2 + x - 1 \ \ = \ \ + \infty \ \ ; $$

that since it is continuous and differentiable everywhere, the Intermediate Value Theorem shows us that there are zeroes in the intervals $ \ \left( -\frac12 \ , \ 0 \right) \ $ and $ \ \left( 0 \ , \ \frac12 \right) \ \ ; $ and, hence, that there must be a "turning-point" in $ \ \left( -\frac12 \ , \ \frac12 \right) \ \ . $  As the second derivative indicates that this function is "concave upward" *everywhere*, there can be no other turning-points, and so no possible "return" to the $ \ x-$ axis.  If there is any further concern, the first derivative $ \ f'(x) \ = \ 4x^3 - 12x^2 + 24x \ = \ 4x · (x^2 - 3x + 6) \ = \ 4x · \left[ \ \left(x - \frac32 \right)^2 + \frac{15}{4} \ \right] \ $ is *non-zero* except at $ \ x = 0 \ \ , $ so the two real zeroes *only* have multiplicity one.

$$ \ \  $$

Incidentally, in a later post on this same polynomial equation [ [The number of distinct real roots of a polynomial of degree 4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771296/the-number-of-distinct-real-roots-of-a-polynomial-of-degree-4) ], it was remarked by the poster that this problem comes from an (unspecified) "competitive exam".  While searching for that online, I found that there are a number of other sites where this problem is discussed:

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-find-number-of-distinct-real-roots-of-x-4-4x-3+12x-2+x-1-0

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8_HD4yqqkE

https://selfstudy365.com/qa/the-number-of-distinct-real-roots-of-x44x3+12x2+x10-152366

https://www.sarthaks.com/563290/the-number-of-distinct-real-roots-of-x-4-4x-3-12x-2-x-1-0-is

https://www.toppr.com/ask/en-ae/question/the-number-of-distinct-real-roots-ofx4-4x3-12x2-x-1/

etc.  This particular polynomial seems rather widely (re-)used for some reason.  (I haven't located the purported exam source.)